# XmlReader(Stream(fileName) -> MemoryStream) slower than XmlReader(fileName)

Tags: c#, performance, stream, xmlreader, memorystream

Please forgive my bad english.

I want to read large XML files (> 2GB). I saw several posts about it and figured out to use XmlReader.

For test purposes, I have created a 500MB XML and make 2 code :

First one :

```
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
Stream file = File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName);
file.CopyTo(mem);
mem.Position = 0;
file.Close();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mem);
// work with reader
```

Second one:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ofd.FileName);
// work with reader
```

ofd.FileName : is the name of path of the xml file.

work with reader : is the same in the two algorithms.

The speed of my RAM is : 15GB/sec
The speed of my ssd is : 150MB/sec

I thought that the first algorithm will be faster by at least 100 time. But in real, the second algorithm is faster.

First algorithm duration : 10500 milliseconds.

Second algorithm duration : 9500 milliseconds.

Why ? Is it because the program should cross over several abstract layer in the first algorithm ?

Thank you for any information.

Comment: You're not showing enough information about how you benchmark. One second or 10% difference may very well be the JITter warming up. Perform a proper benchmark and you'll probably see they perform equally.

Comment: What are you measuring in the first case? (Does it include the reading of the file, or not?) If it includes the time taken to read the file, why would you expect it to be "faster by at least 100 time"?

Comment: @CodeCaster : var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); before the algorithms
And :
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
after the algorithm

Comment: This will work in exactly the same way that taking 128kbps mp3 files and recoding them at 320kpbs *perceptibly* increases the quality of the sound.

Comment: I thought it will be faster because, in the first case : we read all the file in the memory and we work we the memory.
Instead of the second case where we do access to the xml file every time we use the xmlreader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlReader` is a forward-only reader, so with the `MemoryStream` approach you're going through the entire file exactly twice.

Even though the second run is directly from memory, you've already had the "disk" penalty when prebuffering, so the overhead is simply running over all data again.

Comment: You are right, i forgot that in the first case, it reads the file twice.
The copyTo take 1500 milliseconds.

Comment: If the copyTo take 1500 milliseconds, it means that "work with reader" take 9000 milliseconds.
So it's a little bit faster than the second algorithm.
Now it makes more sense.
But should it not go much faster?

Comment: @steacker The OS is quite good at prebuffering file data, I don't know exactly what happens under the hood though. One test may even influence the other if the OS decides to keep file data in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)
I'll go for the second approach as I don't know if the user will have enough memory.